# specifying the filename in a makefile

Tags: linux, gnu-make, makefile

I'm new to this and trying to create a makefile where I could, for example, run:

```
make -f mymakefile testfile
```

and the makefile would find testfile.java (which exists in the directory I'm running from), compile it, and run the code.

Instead, I must be confused with how automatic variables work and after working all afternoon I still get the error:

```
make: Nothing to be done for `testfile'.
```

Any help would be appreciated and my code is below:

```
JC=javac
JVM=java
JFLAGS= -g
RM = rm -f
CFLAGS =
CXX = gcc
NAME = *
.SUFFIXES: .java .class

all: run

NAME: 
        $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -o $^ $@
        echo $(NAME)

$(NAME).class: $(NAME)
        $(JC) $(JFLAGS) $(NAME).java

run: $(NAME).class
        $(JVM) $(NAME)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
        $(RM) $(NAME).class
```

I've tried just having it echo 'testfile' to better understand how automatic variables work, but I couldn't get that to work correctly either.

Comment: `$<` is the incoming source filename. `$@` is the output filename. If you had one source file, the recipe might be crafted like `$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $<`. Also, `$(CC)` uses `$(CFLAGS)`, and `$(CXX)` uses `$(CXXFLAGS)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The arguments on the make command line select the targets to build.  You can't pass values to variables in the same way you would with a shell script (like you're trying to do with "NAME".)

If you really want to pass a value for a variable, the command would be:

```
NAME=testfile make -f mymakefile
```

Comment: Instead of passing via the environment, you probably want to override the `NAME` in the Makefile: `make -f mymakefile NAME=testfile`.

Comment: You can however use pattern rules. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html#Pattern-Rules) to create rules from arbitrary names. [For example](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Examples.html#Pattern-Examples):

```
%.bin : %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

When you call `make test.bin`, this matches pattern rule `%.bin`, where `%` matches `test`. Then [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html#Automatic-Variables) `$<` substitutes the source file and `$@` substitutes the target file. What actually runs is something like `g++ -O3 -o test.bin test.cpp`.